# In alien invation pygame why this error shows " 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'get_rect' "?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

In the alien invasion pygame, why does the below error show?

> 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'get_rect'

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):

    def __init__(self,ai_settings,screen):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen=screen
        self.ai_settings=ai_settings

        #alien image
        self.image=pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()

        #new alien near top of screen
        self.rect.x=self.rect.width
        self.rect.y=self.rect.height

        #alien's position
        self.x=float(self.rect.x)

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)

    def check_edges(self):
        #true if alien at ages of screen
        screen_rect=self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right :
            return True
        elif self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True

    def update(self):
        self.x += (self.ai_settings.alien_speed_factor * self.ai_settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x=self.x
```

Comment: How you create the instance of `Alien`? It seems that a `pygame.Rect` object is passed to the argument `screen` of the constructor of `Alien`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

screen is a pygame.Rect object which as stated has no get_rect method. You need to pass a Surface object into screen not a Rect object.

See:

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode